# How to create a arc at the top right side of layout with jetpack compose android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create an arc or curve on the top right side of a layout along with a floating action button like the attached reference in Jetpack Compose.

I drew this curve using the Bezier curve method but failed to achieve the desired result.

Reference image:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ec5Z.jpg)

```kt
     Surface(
            modifier = modifier,
            shape = shape,
            shadowElevation = elevation,
            color = color,
            contentColor = contentColor
        ) {
            Column {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(diameter))
                content()

            }
        }
```

And For Shape:

```kt
fun Path.roundedRectanglePath(
    size: Size,
    cornerRadius: Float,
    fabRadius: Float,
) {

    val centerX = size.width / 1.2f
    val x0 = centerX - fabRadius * 1.45f
    val y0 = 0f

    // offset of the first control point (top part)
    val topControlX = x0 + fabRadius * .5f

    // offset of the second control point (bottom part)
    val bottomControlY = y0 + fabRadius

    // first curve
    // set the starting point of the curve (P2)
    val firstCurveStart = Offset(x0, y0)

    // set the end point for the first curve (P3)
    val firstCurveEnd = Offset(centerX, fabRadius * 1f)

    // set the first control point (C1)
    val firstCurveControlPoint1 = Offset(
        x = topControlX, y = y0
    )

    // set the second control point (C2)
    val firstCurveControlPoint2 = Offset(
        x = x0, y = bottomControlY
    )


    // second curve
    // end of first curve and start of second curve is the same (P3)
    val secondCurveStart = Offset(
        x = firstCurveEnd.x, y = firstCurveEnd.y
    )

    // end of the second curve (P4)
    val secondCurveEnd = Offset(
        x = centerX + fabRadius * 1.45f, y = 0f
    )

    // set the first control point of second curve (C4)
    val secondCurveControlPoint1 = Offset(
        x = secondCurveStart.x + fabRadius, y = bottomControlY
    )

    // set the second control point (C3)
    val secondCurveControlPoint2 = Offset(
        x = secondCurveEnd.x - fabRadius / 2, y = y0
    )


    // Top left arc
    val radius = cornerRadius * 2

    arcTo(
        rect = Rect(
            left = 0f, top = 0f, right = radius, bottom = radius
        ), startAngleDegrees = 180.0f, sweepAngleDegrees = 90.0f, forceMoveTo = false
    )



    lineTo(x = firstCurveStart.x, y = firstCurveStart.y)

    // bezier curve with (P2, C1, C2, P3)
    cubicTo(
        x1 = firstCurveControlPoint1.x,
        y1 = firstCurveControlPoint1.y,
        x2 = firstCurveControlPoint2.x,
        y2 = firstCurveControlPoint2.y,
        x3 = firstCurveEnd.x,
        y3 = firstCurveEnd.y
    )

    // bezier curve with (P3, C4, C3, P4)
    cubicTo(
        x1 = secondCurveControlPoint1.x,
        y1 = secondCurveControlPoint1.y,
        x2 = secondCurveControlPoint2.x,
        y2 = secondCurveControlPoint2.y,
        x3 = secondCurveEnd.x,
        y3 = secondCurveEnd.y
    )

    lineTo(x = size.width - cornerRadius, y = 0f)

    // Top right arc
    arcTo(
        rect = Rect(
            left = size.width - radius, top = 0f, right = size.width, bottom = radius
        ), startAngleDegrees = -90.0f, sweepAngleDegrees = 90.0f, forceMoveTo = false
    )

    lineTo(x = 0f + size.width, y = size.height - cornerRadius)

    // Bottom right arc
    arcTo(
        rect = Rect(
            left = size.width - radius,
            top = size.height - radius,
            right = size.width,
            bottom = size.height
        ), startAngleDegrees = 0f, sweepAngleDegrees = 90.0f, forceMoveTo = false
    )

    lineTo(x = cornerRadius, y = size.height)

    // Bottom left arc
    arcTo(
        rect = Rect(
            left = 0f, top = size.height - radius, right = radius, bottom = size.height
        ), startAngleDegrees = 90.0f, sweepAngleDegrees = 90.0f, forceMoveTo = false
    )

    lineTo(x = 0f, y = cornerRadius)
    close()
}
```

Update:
Successfully drew an arc on the right side with canvas and draw arc. But failed to give some radius to its corners
[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQURx.png)